# What the programing language can send http post or get from client in web brower?

Tags: programming-languages

What the programing language can send http post or get from client in web brower  ?

i think flash actionscript or ajax or java applet not working for cross domain security thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nothing in the browser sandbox will get past cross-domain security (which is exactly the point of having a sandbox in the first place).

You'd have to write a native browser plugin or use a Java applet that asks for "unlimited system access".

Another option would be to use the one domain that you can access via XHR to act as a proxy (have some code there that fetches the result from the domain you really want to access). You can even forward cookies and such, but for the target domain it looks like the request is coming from your data center (not the end user's browser).

Answer (score 0):

You can send requests with javascript using XHR (you may have heard this referred to as AJAX before) if you control the destination server, you can host a page on the second domain that does the ajax request and stores the result in a window level variable, and put that in an iframe for the first domain. After that, any time you want to make the request, you use javascript to refresh the iframe and grab the variable out of it.

Total hack, but AFAIK its the only way to do it.